# Reduce the parent table height if child table reduces in IE

Tags: html

```
<div style="height:100%">
 <table style="height:100%" id="parenttable">
 <tr>
   <td>
      <table id="childtable" style="height:100%">
      <tr>
        <td>
       </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

I am doing dynamic hide/show of the data in child table. So it's height is reduced. But that inturn not reducing the height of parent table. It occurs only in IE

Answer (score 0):

Why you haven't used 2 seperate div's? it would be more better by specifing the css class & relevant javascript.